# Parent child structure or serialised array in MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, structure

I am trying to make a good decision about how to structure my MySQL database.

I can best explain this by example:

I have a table called `customers`. A customer can control one or more `sites`.
`Sites` has his own table.
The tables `customers` and `sites` have a primary key `id (AUTO-INCREMENT)`.
Most customers can modify multiple "sites" and we are growing towards 100.000 customers. All I need to do with this information is to check if a customer can edit a site.

The question is: how can I store my data best if I want to keep the queries to a minimum and the performance best?
1. I create a serialized array of all "sites" that a customer can edit and put it in a column in `customers` table.
2. I create a child-table for `customers` called `customer-site` in which I write all site_id's that the customer has access to.

As you probably can read I don't have a lot of knowledge, so any information why is very appreciated!

Best regards,
Abayob

Comment: Arrays is a very bad idea. Go for the normalised data, customer_site table. It will be easy for everyone to understand as it is a very common choice, easy to work with and fast enough to query through. Arrays have none of those advantages. You do not even have native array support in mysql. There is no other good way to do it besides option 2.

Comment: Anything with a serialised array is a difficult to process in MySQL (it can be done - but probably only worthwhile to show the nasty SQL to someone to convince them not to do it!). A comma separated list of site ids is slightly better (can be accessed using FIND_IN_SET), but not efficient or that flexible. To keep the number of queries to a minimum and efficient option 2 is the best choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a **`permissions`** table which will hold two columns **`short_name`, `name`**. You should create another table which will hold the customer permissions to sites **`customer_permission_site`** with **`customer_id`, `site_id`, `permission_short_name`**. Then check with the short name field from your code if the user has permissions.

Your **`short_name`** field in permissions table will be primary key for the table.

> **Benefits for this architecture**

1. You can easily set an user to a site for edit, delete etc permissions.
2. You can set permissions to be given a user to a site in permissions table
3. Normalized & easy to search & retrieve.

Answer (score 1):

Mysql normalization rules say that option 2 is the way to go. It's easier for you to edit too directly in the database. With this you can also bind foreign keys to both, and cascade deletion of a site/customer (also removes the row in the linking table)